# how to change the value of a raster of 2 by 2 by the value of a raster of 10 by 10 in qgis?

Tags: raster, qgis, landscape, pyqgis

I have a raster with a cell size of 2 by 2. its values goes from 0 to 3 (which is btw a categorical variable that I changed into a raster).
I am working on ecological data so I want to assign to the raster of 2 by 2 the value from a 10 by 10 which means extracted from the 25 cells of 2 by 2.
So what I want is from 1 raster of 2 by 2, I will create 4 rasters.
the first raster created will be the percentage of 2 by 2 cell in the 10 by 10 cell where the value is 0,
the second raster created will be the percentage of 2 by 2 cell in the 10 by 10 cell where the value is 1,
and so on for value 2 and value 3.

How can i do that in qgis? or with python code?

I actually tried to separate every raster to each value but I really dont know what to do else.